# Can one avoid multiple DOM elements with same id, when using Backbone/Marionette view instances?

Tags: marionette

When I create multiple view instances of the Marionette view which is linked with a template html with ids, these would get duplicated for multiple instances of these views.

While it works correctly, I feel that there ought to be more architecturally correct way of doing this.

The example code is like below.

```
Template:
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/template">
    <div id="myDiv">
        <input type="text" id="myText"/>
        <input type="button" id="myBtn" value="Click me!"/>
    </div>
</script>
View:
MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#myTemplate',
    events: {
        'click #myBtn' : 'myFunc'       //Correctly identifies its own 'myBtn'
    },
    myFunc : function() {
        alert($('myText').val());     //Again, picks own 'myText'
    }
});
var v1= new MyView();
v1.render();
var v2= new MyView();
v2.render();     //Duplicate IDs now present in DOM
```

I need some unique identification of these DOM elements and hence the ids.
Even when tying the model to this view, we need some way to identify these DOM elements.

What is the correct way of doing this without duplicating the ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must go for unique IDs to make sure no one accidentally duplicates a class name inside a view, you can use:

1. Underscore's `uniqueId` method to generate a unique ID for each DOM element inside the view, like: `<input type="text" id= <%= _.uniqueId("myText_") %> />` This will just make sure that IDs are not duplicated. But they're not very helpful if you need to identify the elements by these IDs.
2. Marionette's `TemplateHelpers` which allow you to use helper functions from inside the templates:

   ```
   //Define this inside your view:
     templateHelpers: function() {  
         var that = this;
         return {  
            getIdSuffix : function() {  return that.idSuffix; }
               /*Where idSuffix is passed to the view during instantiation
                 and assigned to this.idSuffix */   
         };  
     }

   //In the template:
     <input type="text" id= <%= "myText_" + getIdSuffix() %> />
   ```

You now know before runtime what DOM IDs you will have, provided care is taken not to give the same idSuffix to more than one view instance.

Comment: Thanks. This should prove to be helpful for generating separate unique IDs even for the multiple instances of a view operating on the same template while statically binding them to a model.
This would also not force me to use the class attribute for the DOM for unique identification (which it is not designed to be used for).
This certainly seems to be worth investigating and adopting.

Comment: jQueryUI's tabs is one scenario I recently came across that demands ID for its divs. Instantiating a tabs view would duplicate these IDs in a page, making it invalid HTML. This solution helps in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the id to the view when you create it:

Template:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/template">
    <input type="text" class="js-myText"/>
    <input type="button" class="js-myBtn" value="Click me!"/>
</script>
```

View def:

```
MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#myTemplate',
    events: {
        'click #myBtn' : 'myFunc'       //Correctly identifies its own 'myBtn'
    },
    myFunc : function() {
        alert($('myText').val());     //Again, picks own 'myText'
    }
});
```

Instanciation:

```
var v1= new MyView({ id: "view" + number});
v1.render();
```

Then you can provide dynamic `id` values for your views (e.g. by using a model id).

That said, when using Marionette you shouldn't need to call `render`: you should instead `show` a view within a region. Take a look at the [free sample](http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf) to my [Marionette book](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction/) to get you up to speed.

Comment: Sorry if I did not make myself clear earlier.
What I am worried about is "myText" id of <input> dom child element which will get repeated inside the view even when the container element would have a dynamically created id as given by you.
How would I now deal with two (or more) view instances with "mytText" as IDs of child elements.

Comment: That wouldn't happen with my answer: there is no `id` attribute in the template, and each time you instantiate a view you provide a different id (e.g. "view1", "view2"). If you need different ids, obviously you'll need to provide the different id value yourself. If you don't need the HTML `id` attribute, simply remove it (Backbone doesn't need it in views). Does this make this clearer?

Comment: Thank you for being patient with me, but I am worried about the HTML id that was given in the template for both the <input> DOM elements, as in example with the first text box with id "myText" and id of "myBtn" for the second button.
For "view1" and "view2" the text box and button IDs would be duplicate now.
I feel these would be necessary to tie the model with text box of "view1" and text box of "view2".

Comment: Oops didn't pay attention to those ids. I changed the template in my answer to use classes instead: you don't need ids, because you'll be able to access (e.g.) the button with the "#view1 .js-myBtn" selector. Furthermore, you probably don't need to use a view-level id either, since you can access (e.g.) the button from within the view code by using `this.$el.find(".js-myBtn")`.

Comment: Thank you.
Well I had heard of this solution from my colleagues but could not believe them, since I did not like the idea of using "class" attribute of the DOM element to identify it uniquely.
Another developer who maintains the code would come along and use this class for the peer DOM element not realizing that this class name is used for uniquely identify this DOM and should not be used in the template again.
But it seems that there is no other way. And whatever way the creation of Backbone/Marionette view instances & using templates pushed us into was a blind alley.
Thank you once again.

Comment: This is the most maintainable way to handle it. You can also have unique IDs for all the input elements, but usually it isn't necessary: each view should handle its own element, so the class only needs to be unique within the view. If something else needs to interact with that element, it should call a method on the view.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, don't use an `id` if it's not unique.  Use a class or some other way of identifying the element.

You can use any jQuery selector to locate the element you want, ranging from the insane and brittle:

`this.$('div > input:first'); // don't actually do this!`

to the slower but semantically better:

`this.$('[data-element-type="some-text-box-descriptive-name"]');`

Although in reality, using a class is best, because that's what a class is for - for identifying a type of element. I can see that a maintainer might not know not to change your class in the template, so a data-attribute might be acceptable, or maybe even (in this case):

`this.$('input[type=text]');`